# React/Typescript return Error EOENT after added typescript to project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

Hi i just pull project from my team into mine local git and i am getting this error:

```
./src/components/SubjectDashboard/SubjectDashboard.js
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/xyxyxyxy/Code/reactnetcoreapp/xxxx/ClientApp/src/components/SubjectDashboard/SubjectDashboard.js'
```

I am sure this file is exist. It is file itried to remake into tsx. I deleted node_modules and tried npm install again but nothing changed. How can i solve this please?

Comment: Could be the file extension, are you sure the file name is exactly that and ends in `.js`?

Comment: no file name is SubjectDashboard.tsx so .js is suspicious but i don't lnow why it is showing

Comment: Have you restarted your node dev server? Sometimes when it infers the file extension it gets stuck with the old extension until restarting

Comment: When exactly are you getting this error? While running `npm install`? If so, give `sudo npm install` a try (assuming you're on a mac / linux system)

Comment: After restarting node dev server it show other error from typescript so i think  that was it. Thx for help